# Authorize all controllers in a given namespace?

Tags: fluent-security

Is it possible to apply an AuthorizeAttribute to all controllers within a given namespace using FluentSecurity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using `ForAllControllersInNamespaceContainingType<TType>()` or `ForActionsMatching(info => *predicate*)` in FluentSecurity 2.0 (currently in beta).

You can read more about it in the documentation here: https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/wiki/Securing-controllers